# Which workflow gem is thread safe in mutli tenant Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, state-machine

Is there any `thread safe` workflow gem for multi tenant Rails app? The `geekq/workflow` is not thread safe because a user who logs in late overwrites previous user's `workflow specification` which means at any time there is only one copy of `workflow spec` for one running application. `AASM` seems define the `workflow spec` per class (may be wrong) which is the same as geekq/workflow.

Is there any ruby workflow gem which has been proved to be thread safe in multi tenant Rails app?

Comment: Why would this not be thread-safe? What exactly are you doing with it? Why does multi-tenant have any impact on a state machine?

Comment: If every tenant has its own `workflow specification` (ex `initial state => ceo approve => pay` for `user a`, for `user b` it is `initial state => acct approve`), let's assume `user  a` logs in first. He has `initial state => ceo approve => pay`. When `user b` logs in, the spec changes to `initial state => acct approve`. When `user a` consults workflow and he get `user b's` `initial state => acct approve` instead of his own.

Comment: not familiar with these gems, but it's worth asking if you've considered trying to write a threadsafe wrapper over the gem. For example, if a gem is define a class variable, you could probably make a custom class which inherits from the gem's base class. With some metaprogramming, you could do this dynamically.

Comment: Usually unless you're manipulating the same object from multiple threads this isn't an issue. The primary thing to look out for is singleton classes and globals, though I don't see anything in your question here that suggests that's a problem. Maybe what you're asking about is *race conditions* and not threading or multi-tenant problems.

Comment: `max pleaner`, interesting idea. The `workflow_spec` is currently defined at class level. If we can wrap the gem and convert the spec into an instance method, the problem should be solved as I image. Is there a good example of wrapper gem of similar kind? This is something new to me. thanks.

Comment: `tadman`, if the `workflow_spec` were defined as singleton class then, there may be no problem. What observed in debugger is that when the 2nd user logs in, the previous user's `workflow_spec` is there for the new user. Maybe it should be called racing. The problem is more related to  the architecture. The current design introduces a racing condition in certain use case.